# Python for maya passing attribute between functions

Tags: python, function, constraints, maya

I'm trying to create a script to add new space in existing rigs, by adding new Attribute and connect to the user selection.
For instance the animator wants to constraint the hand to the head, or to the body, hips, whatever, in order to follow and get a perfect connection...

This is what I have so far:

`https://pastebin.com/raw/RCFGN9jp`

```
import maya.cmds as mc

def add_attribute_and_create_group(*args):
    attribute_name = mc.textField(attribute_field, query=True, text=True)
    selected_objects = mc.ls(selection=True)
    
    created_groups = []
    
    for selected_object in selected_objects:
        if not mc.objExists("{0}.{1}".format(selected_object, attribute_name)):
            mc.addAttr(selected_object, ln=attribute_name, at="double", min=0, max=1, dv=0, keyable=True)

        group_name = selected_object + "_spaceGrp"
        if not mc.objExists(group_name):
            new_group = mc.group(selected_object, name=group_name)
            mc.xform(new_group, centerPivots=True)
            created_groups.append(new_group)
    
    print('Returned object is:', created_groups)
    return created_groups



def create_parent_constraint(*args):
    selected_objects = mc.ls(selection=True)
    if not selected_objects:
        print("Nothing selected.")
        return

    groups = mc.ls("*_spaceGrp")
    if not groups:
        print("No group created.")
        return

    group_name = groups[0]
    prefix = group_name.split("_spaceGrp")[0]
    constraint_name = prefix + "_parentConstraint"

    for selected_object in selected_objects:
        mc.parentConstraint(selected_object, group_name, maintainOffset=True, name=constraint_name)
        print("ParentConstraint created btween", selected_object, "and", group_name)

    constraint_node = mc.ls(constraint_name)[0]
    first_selected_object = selected_objects[0]

    mc.select(constraint_node, first_selected_object)
    print("selceted constraint:", constraint_node)
    print("selecting the first user selection:", first_selected_object)



# Creazione della finestra
window = mc.window(title="Add Attribute")
mc.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)
attribute_field = mc.textField(text="")
mc.button(label="Add Space", command=add_attribute_and_create_group)
mc.button(label="Parent", command=create_parent_constraint)
mc.showWindow(window)
```

the user select the hand (for instance) and through the GUI, he add the name space he wants to use and click on Add Space. By doing this, the code add the new attribute and create a group on the selection
Next step the user select the control where he wants to connect to, in this example the head, and click on the Parent button…and the script connect the previous created group to this last selection…

When I do this for the first time, it works as expected but when I try to do it to the other hand, the script connect the previous created group and not the new one...

The script is not completed yet, I mean it actually doesnt connect the attribute to make the hand follow the head, I need first to understand how to fix this issue...

I guess its probably because im not transferring the argument between the 2 function in a proper way….

Basically I’d like that after the click of the Parent button, would be like a new whole action, with new variables etc … I tried to wrap around a class, but doesnt change too much…

Thanks in advance if you find a sec to check it

Comment: The reason my be that you list all geo `groups = mc.ls("*_spaceGrp")` and then you use the first one what looks not correct to me because you cannot be sure which is the first one.

Comment: Yes, you're right im trying to have a more specific name.. no luck so far
Thanks Haggi!